# Relative kinematics curved space

Tags: kinematics, velocity, curvature

I know that in a general curved manifold it is possible to describe parametric curves. Then, the length of the curve will be a indipendent from the coordinate system used --> the metric tensor transforms properly to guarantee this.

So far so good. Now, let's take the time "t" as parameter for a generic curve on a curved manifold. If I consider two observers which are in relative motion on the manifold,  their coordinate system relation will be a function of t. So the coordinate transformation depends on the parameter chosen to parametrize the curves on the manifold.

I know how to deal with this problems in 3d euclidean space --> relative kinematics, with concepts like relative velocity etc. But what if the manifold is curved? Is there a relative kinematics notion also in this scenario? In this case, where could I study deeper this concept? (I could not find this on the web)

Comment: Note, a $3d$ Eclidean manifold is a Rienammian manifold. In any case, you'll need 2 parameters in $3d$ Euclidean space to describe a curved surface. I'd recommend try using the Frenet Frame and parameterizing the curves using the arc length. Also I'd recommend studing differential geometry and moving this post to "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation